# How can i get a mouse move event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that something will happen when moving the mouse cursor around.
But i'm not sure what event will be for it.
Is there any onmousemove event or i should use onmousedown and onmouseup somehow ?

Thank you for the help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Orbit with zoom")]
public class MouseOrbitImproved : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 5.0f;
    public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

    public float yMinLimit = 3.0f;//-20f;
    public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

    public float distanceMin = .5f;
    public float distanceMax = 15f;

    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;

    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        x = angles.y;
        y = angles.x;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (target && Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
            y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

            y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

            distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
            {
                distance -= hit.distance;
            }
            Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
            Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

            transform.rotation = rotation;
            transform.position = position;

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed);

            if (target != null)
            {
                target.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed);
            }
        }
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0)`

This will detect any mouse movement